# How to stream a video between two clients using SignalR (.NET Core 3.0)?

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, c#-8.0

I'm trying to create an application that records a video with a RaspberryPi camera and streams that video to a web browser.

I've managed to establish the individual *Client->Server* streaming and *Server->Client* streaming connections using the [JavaScript SignalR libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/javascript-client?view=aspnetcore-3.1) and now I need to somehow connect those two functions on the server in order to send a chunk of data to the browser as soon as it is recieved from the RaspberryPi.

These are the two examples from the Microsoft’s documentation:

```cs
public async Task UploadStream(IAsyncEnumerable<string> stream)
{
    await foreach (var item in stream)
    {
        // Here I need to send  the chunk (item) to the browser
        Debug.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

```cs
public async IAsyncEnumerable<string> DownloadStream(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
   while (true) // While there is data to stream
   {
       yield return "data"; // Return chunks to the browser
   }
}
```

Those examples are written using C# 8.0 `IAsyncEnumerable` and I would like to use them this way.

I tried to use a `Queue` to store data (enqueue on upload and dequeue on download) but the memory between the two connected clients is not shared.

Also, I don't know if I can use the method `Clients.Others.SendAsync()` because it is used to invoke a method from a normal SignalR app and in the documentation for the JavaScript library it uses the method `stream()`.

```js
connection.start().then(() => {
    console.log("connected");
    connection.stream("DownloadStream").subscribe({
        next: item => {
            console.log(item);
        },
        complete: () => {
            console.log("completed");
        },
        error: err => {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm working on a same project and using Kafka as a pub/sub (whenever messages arrive it pass to the client). the project is still under development and I will share it very soon.

Comment: @Soren any update on your kafka pub/sub project? I'm in a mix of using kafka or SignalR and WebRTC, need to be sure of the better option.

Comment: @Jeff, I believe the best solution for sharing video between two clients is WebRTC, Bytheway takes a look at this article [Distributed Video Streaming with Python and Kafka](https://medium.com/@kevin.michael.horan/distributed-video-streaming-with-python-and-kafka-551de69fe1dd) - for distributing a video stream through Kafka. My project is still under development (it's not runnable now) and I didn't find a final solution for that. https://github.com/SorenZ/KafkaVideoStreaming

Comment: Thanks for this @Soren. My backend is in .Net Core too. 

@Nacho, can you please share the link to this: `These are the 2 examples from the Microsoft Documentation` ?

Comment: The signalr hub is created on each request meaning it will not hold state between requests. A quick fix would be to statically initialize the queue or even better a blocking queue. Even better solution would be to create a simple caching service and register it in the DI as a singleton. Then persist to cache and stream from it.